# promise chain when rejected but only have then implermented

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I was reading stuffs about promise and fetch and got really confused. I got the following code from [Introduction to fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch).

My question is: what happens if `status` returns a rejected `promise`? `then(json)` is chained after `then(status)`, does that mean `then(json)` won't do anything since `then(json)` only gets executed when `status` returnes a resolved promise? Or does that mean the chain just keeps passing all the `then`s if status returns rejected promise until it reaches reach `catch` at the bottom, and the `catch` catches error?

Or if I was wrong, what is the correct interpretation of this code?

```
function status(response) {  
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {  
    return Promise.resolve(response)  
  } else {  
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))  
  }  
}

function json(response) {  
  return response.json()  
}

fetch('users.json')  
  .then(status)  
  .then(json)  
  .then(function(data) {  
    console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);  
  }).catch(function(error) {  
    console.log('Request failed', error);  
  });
```

Comment: "*does that mean then(json) won't do anything since then(json) only gets executed when status returnes a resolved promise?*" - yes, the success callback (`json`) does not get executed when the promise fails. However something happens: the promise that the `.then(…)` returned does get rejected, so that the error propagates.
"*Or does that mean the chain just keeps passing all the thens if status returns rejected promise until it reaches reach catch at the bottom*" - Yes.

Comment: if `.then(status)` stage gets rejected, just by adding an `onRejected` callback to `.then(json, onRejected)` stage you may handle the rejected promise earlier and take an action like trying once more etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my early days of trying to understand promises, I thought of the .then chain as being two chains ... success and rejection

a rejection or error causes the "execution" to "jump" from success to rejection

if a rejection handler returns a value that isn't a rejected promised, the "execution" will "jump" to the success chain

Note: my earliest exposure to promises had no `.catch` ... because `.then` actually accepts two arguments `onFullfilled` and `onRejected` - if either of those is not a `function` it is ignored -

So, your code can be written as follows:

```
function status(response) {  
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {  
    return Promise.resolve(response)  
  } else {  
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))  
  }  
}

function json(response) {  
  return response.json()  
}

function log(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.log('Request failed', error);
}

fetch('users.json')  
  .then(status,   null)  
  .then(json,     null)  
  .then(log,      null)
  .then(null,     handleError);
```

Now it's fairly clear that given an error in function stats, the "on rejected" chain is in "effect" (I really need to think of better terminology), and there's nothing in the `reject` chain until the very bottom, therefore, that's the next code that gets executed

> Note `.catch` in some Promise libraries is simply the following

```
Promise.prototype.catch = function catch(onRejected) {
    return this.then(null, onRejected);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When a promise gets rejected it goes directly to the `.catch()` without executing anything else of the chain.

So if `status` returns a `Promise.reject` only the `catch` function will execute.